# Django - CreateView form on existing view and url

Tags: python, django, forms, url, modelform

I'm using django generic views in my project CRUD. The CreateView class uses the following url to work:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^create', BookCreate.as_view(model=Books, template_name='Myproj/book_create.html'),                         name='book_create'),
```

If I go the www.mywebsite.com/create the form appears just how I wanted it.

My problem is that I want to incorporate the form on another page, that already has a url, a view and a template. The url is like the one bellow:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^author/(?P<id>[0-9]{1,})/$', author_view_handler, name='author_view'),
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: How familiar are you with working with forms in non-generic views? In other words, do you just need to know how to get the form class, or do you need to know how to process the form in your `author_view_handler` view?

Comment: I know how to process forms in non-generic views, my problems begins at the generic ones. The CreateView creates the form for me at the `/create` url that redirects to a template. My problem is that I want to go to the `author/id`url and see the form there. It seems that the form needs a URL just for him.

Comment: The generic views use a plain `ModelForm`, so it should be as simple as creating one for the `Books` model either in an explicit class or using `modelform_factory`, then instantiating an empty one in the `author_view_handler`. I'd probably omit whatever field tracks relationships between authors and books from the form and set that in my view.

Comment: Ok, so now my question changes. How do I call the BookCreate(CreateView) class inside my `author_view_handler` view, knowing that I've to pass it the name of the model (Books)? I am passing the Model just in the url. And I do I pass it to the template?

Comment: You don't call a create class, you call the `save` method on the `modelform`. Possibly with `commit=False` if there's a many-to-one relationship from books to authors, so you can set the author field and then save the model. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method. As for passing it to the template, just put it in your context.

Comment: I understand that. Thanks. But, the form dont appears on the template and i have the `{{ form.as_p }}` on it. It doesn't appear because I am passing the template name on the URL `template_name='Myproj/book_create.html`, but now I don't have it. Because the URL I am in is `author/id`.

Answer (score 0):

The `CreateView` uses a `ModelForm`. If you want to use it also, you need to create a a Book model form yourself, something like this:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class BookModelForm(ModelForm):
    pass
```

And then instantiate it `form=BookModelForm()` and pass it to the context of your `author_view_handler` view.

However I am not really sure why you would want to do something like that...

Update: To pass it to your view, use

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def author_view_handler(request):
    form = BookModelForm()
    return render(request, 'author_view_handler.html', {"form": form},
```

The above just passes the form to the author_view_handler view and *does not* contain any form handling code.

Comment: or maybe OP wants to combine several url+view+template in one template, something like this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/uJ_fzpPzUkE

Comment: I already use a ModelForm for the books. I just dont know how to pass it to the `author_view_handler` view. I want to access the `author/id` url and see the form there. How do I pass it to the context?